# How to set QPixmap in QQuickImageProvider class from another class?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am developing an application using QML and C++, the goal is to download an image named **"test.jpg"** from a HTTP server and show it in a QML Image component without saving it in hard disk drive.

The class **"AppController"** downloads the image "test.jpg" from server and store in a global QPixmap variable named **"imageReadFromServer"**.

```
#ifndef APPCONTROLLER_H
#define APPCONTROLLER_H

#include <QObject>

class AppController : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    AppController(QObject *parent = 0);

    Q_INVOKABLE void sendImage(QString _imagePath, QString serverLocation);
    Q_INVOKABLE void readImage(QString serverLocation);

private:
    QByteArray serverResponse;
    QPixmap imageReadFromServer;
};

#endif // APPCONTROLLER_H
```

To display images on QML Image component I know that it is necessary to use **"QQuickImageProvider"** class, I have done one class named **"ImageProvider"** and reimplemented its virtual method *QPixmap  requestPixmap()* to handle when QML requests image showing. To test if everything was working well until now, I used the next example code provided by Qt documentation that returns a QPixmap filled with blue color:

```
QPixmap ImageProvider::requestPixmap(const QString &id, QSize *size, const QSize &requestedSize)
{
    qDebug() << "pixmap requested";

    int width = 160;
    int height = 100;

    if(size)
        *size = QSize(width,height);
    QPixmap pixmap(requestedSize.width() > 0 ? requestedSize.width() : width,
                   requestedSize.height() > 0 ? requestedSize.height() : height);
    pixmap.fill(QColor("blue").rgba());
    //return pixmap;

    return pixmap;
}
```

In **main.cpp** I added its respective image provider.

```
engine.addImageProvider(QLatin1String("imagefromserver"), new ImageProvider);
```

When download button is clicked on QML, it calls **ImageProvider** class method successfully:

```
onClicked:  {
        imageVisualizer.visible = true
        imageVisualizer.source = "image://imagefromserver/"
    }
```

---

**What I need is:**

When **requestPixmap()** method from **ImageProvider** class is called, it should return the global variable **imageReadFromServer** already stored in **AppController** class.

I have tried to make **AppController** class inherits directly from QQuickImageProvider but it didn't work because **imageReaderFromServer** value was weirdly cleared just before call **requestPixmap()**.

I thought that I could use SIGNALS and SLOTS to pass QPixmap between classes but QQuickImageProvider doesn't inherits from QObject, so I cannot use them.

I appreciate any suggestion.
Thanks.

---

### **EDIT**

I have again tried to implement QQuickImageProvider inheritance in `AppController` class. It is already working, the mistake was in `main.cpp` file, I was declaring image provider as shown below:

```
AppController applicationController;

QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.addImageProvider(QLatin1String("imagefromserver"), new AppController);
```

This created a new instance of AppController class, and when I accessed to `requestPixmap()` function it couldn't get the global QPixmap variable `imageReadFromServer` because it was created in the instance named `applicationController`. The solution was to assign the same instance to imageProvider as shown below:

```
engine.addImageProvider(QLatin1String("imagefromserver"), &applicationController);
```

Comment: I think the question doesn't relate to QML. You can either use `AppController` as a singleton or implement all the download logic inside it. Anyway, the phrase `imageReaderFromServer value was weirdly cleared` is unclear, you have to provide all suitable source.

Comment: @folibis Excuse me if I didn't explain it clearly, but your comment helped me to understand where could be the issue. I have edited the post with the correction. Thank you.

Comment: @Luis Eduardo : I think it would be more useful to readers to have the answer be an actual answer rather than a question edit.